# Facebook Ad placement within different applications

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ads

I have an Android application (A) that uses Facebook SDK and uses Facebook Audience Network to preview ads.

Now I have another Android application (B) that is not using Facebook SDK but I want to show Facebook ads within it (I'm gonna use Facebook Audience Network SDK).

**Could I create an Ad Placement under application (A) Facebook settings page and use this ad placement within my application (B)?**

Thank you in advance.